# Nested for/while loops for repetition in C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

My goal is to print a cube that has a width/height of a user-defined variable. Why is it that a for loop nested in a while loop can accomplish this whereas a while loop inside a while loop (with different counting variables) cannot?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is `y` reset to `0`? Maybe after `x++;` you add a `y=0;`? For output of a single character, use `putchar ('#');` or `putchar ('\n');` You need to remove `printf ("#")` from the `x` loop)

Comment: Your code would take up a lot less space, be easier to read, and friendly to screenreaders if you edited it into your question as text.

Comment: cannot see the question, i am blocked to see the images, why do we accept this kind of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question, the second example does not print the block because you fail to reset `y = 0;` after you output a row of characters. If you compare with your use of `for` loops, the inner loop begins with `y == 0` each time it is called. In your `while` loop implementation, `y` is never reset.

A complete implementation of your code, resetting `y` as necessary would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void block (void) {
    
    int w = get_int ("What would you like the width/height to be: "),
        x = 0,
        y = 0;
    
    while (x++ < w) {
        while (y++ < w)
            putchar ('#');
        putchar ('\n');
        y = 0;
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    block();
}
```

(**note:** you can move the increment of `x` and `y` out of the loop condition if you like. Also note the output of `'#'` has been removed from the `x`-loop, and `putchar()` has been used to output the single characters rather than calling the variadic `printf()` -- though a good compiler will make that switch for you)

**Example Use/Output**

A couple of examples:

```
$ ./bin/square_while_cs50
What would you like the width/height to be: 5
#####
#####
#####
#####
#####

$ ./bin/square_while_cs50
What would you like the width/height to be: 10
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
```

(**note:** if you actually want to make things look "square", replace `putchar ('#');` with the string `" #"` with `fputs (" #", stdout);`)

Also, please do not post pictures of code, instead copy and paste your code into the question, indented by 4-spaces so it formats as code (or with 3-backticks above and below)

Let me know if you have questions.